# caffe constant output with multilabel regression?

Tags: regression, caffe

As discussed in this PR [#1765](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1765) , I face the same problem.
It's not clear what is the solution to this problem
When I try to do multilabel regression with caffe ,always prediction is constant.
Then after inspecting the weights , I found that the bias of the last fc layer are the exact values of the constant output.
What could be the problem?

Comment: what happens if you do not allow for bias at the last layer? i.e., setting bias_term: false?

Comment: @Shai,Nice idea. I'll try that.

Comment: The loss is simply oscillating after different attempts.One curious observation is that predictions for a single label are close by and either positive or negative. The same model can regress onto each individual variables separately.